# Regular expression to match resources only contained at root

Tags: regex

My regular expression knowledge is lacking and I'm trying to solve the following issue.

I want to write an expression to match only HTML (*.html) files at the root path of a web app. E.g.

The following should match:

> /myfile.html

The following shouldn't match (contains sub-directory):

> /home/myfile.html

My current expression:

> ^/(.*.html)$

is not satisfactory because it will match files in sub-directories.

Can anybody solve this one for me?

Thanks,

Andrew

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
^/([^/]+\.html)$
```

`[^/]+` will match anything else than `/`

the dot before html is escaped to match only a dot and not any character
(see Andrea Spadaccini's answer)

Answer (score 4):

You need to exclude slashes from the `.*` sub-expression:

```
^/([^/]*\.html)$
```

Also, you should escape the dot before html, or else you would match anything ending in html like `/testhtml`.

Comment: +1 very good point to escape the `.` in `.html` (changed this now in my answer)

Answer (score 2):

Use `[^/]` instead of a dot. The brackets make a character class and the caret means the class will not match any character after it. Also make sure to escape the literal dot that you want before the file extension.

This makes the whole expression `^/([^/]*\.html)$`.

Answer (score 2):

You want to exclude slashes from the (.*) portion of the expression.  Also, you should escape the dot that introduces the file extension.  Otherwise, it will match any character.

```
^/([^/]*\.html)$
```

Answer (score 0):

Add ^/, which means a slash within the string won't match the regex.